# Strange problem with object property - present outside of loop, missing inside of loop

Tags: javascript, object

I have a really strange problem right now.

`markers` is an array of objects.

```
0  
     content (String)
     coords (Object)
     gMarker (Object)
1  
     content (String)
     coords (Object)
     gMarker (Object)
2  
     content (String)
     coords (Object)
     gMarker (Object)
```

So far, so good.

The problem:

```
console.dir(markers); 
/**
 * output as expected
 */
for(var i in markers) {
    console.dir(markers[i]); 
    /** 
     * gMarker object is missing!
     * markers[i] suddenly consists just of content and coords
     */
```

How can that be?

**Edit:** It must have had something to do with the "load" callback function of google maps. It fires a bit too early, at least in my case. I replaced that callback (GEvent.addListener(map, "load", callback_fn)) with a simple setTimeout that fires my callback function after 2 seconds, and now everything works as expected.

Either way, this does not explain why the gMarker property is not available inside that for-loop, that can not even be a race condition since the loop starts immediately after that point where the object is still OK.

Comment: did you try console.dir(markers[0]); console.dir(markers[1]); console.dir(markers[2]); ? i guess the problem is for(var i in markers)

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no difference. I also tried for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) - same result.

Comment: Can you try firebug 1.5 and console.log?

Comment: OK Tommy it's getting even more weird ;-) 
Firebug 1-5 and console.log: console.log(markers[i]); ->OK! console.log(markers[i].gMarker); -> undefined!

Comment: try console.log(markers[i]['gMarker']);

Comment: did you use hasOwnProperty method to check if gMarker is a direct attribute of markers[i]? not sure though

Comment: No I did not. Please see my post, I edited it. I am happy that it works for now... but still I would like to know the reason.

Comment: yeah, i want to know the reason too. you can check with this. console.log(markers[i].hasOwnProperty('gMarker')); console.log(markers[i].hasOwnProperty('coords'));
just want to know if gMarker is came from the prototype chain.

Comment: hasOwnProperty('gMarker') returns false, hasOwnProperty('coords') returns true!

Comment: The reason for this is because the gMarker gets set after the other properties. If I put in an empty gMarkers object in the beginning along with coords and content, 
hasOwnProperty('gMarker') returns true too.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be

```
for(var i in markers) {
    console.dir(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, my Firebug console.dir doesn't even work with for-in on an array.

It could have to do with `i` being a global variable set elsewhere, but more than likely this is called due to the property being loaded at a later point in time.  Do you manually set the object, or how is it being loaded?

```
for (var i=markers.length;i--;){
   console.dir(markers[i]);
}
```